# Android: print pretty JSON string is truncated

Tags: android, json, gson

I want to print all `JSON` string received from my server.

So I tried 2 ways:

First with `JSON` (Android SDK) like that:

```
LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "jsonBodyReceived: " + new JSONObject(jsonStr).toString(4));
```

Second with `GSON` like that:

```
mGson = gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "jsonBodyReceived: " + mGson.toJson(new JsonParser().parse(jsonStr)));
```

Unfortunately in both cases, the result is truncated (not at the same place). There is no special characters, etc.

If I print the `JSON` string without format like:

```
mGson = gsonBuilder.create(); // Without pretty option
```

> All the string is printed correctly.

So how can I print with a pretty format my `JSON` string ?